# Make element vertically span whole container

Tags: html, css, web

So you can see what I currently have here: https://steelcowboy.me

Basically what I want is a white content area, grey on the sides and my blue navbar. I don't want any grey atop or below the white part (i.e. I want grey on the sides only, white in the middle). However, I'm not sure what I need to do -- I tried different `display` options for the container element, but the one that worked (flex) then messes up all the content inside. I feel like this is a really simply fix, but can't quite seem to get it. Anyone have an answer? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Steelsite</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#3f51b5">
<style>html,body { height:100%; margin:0; } a {font-weight: bold;} body {background-color:#e0e0e0;} img {max-width:100%; height:auto;} </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    [navbar in here]
 <main>
            <div class="container white">
                <h3 class="center-align">Welcome to the site of James Heald</h3>


                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col s12 m6">
                        <div class="flow-text" style="font-size: 125%;">
                            <p>I'm a teen who loves bike riding, photography, travel, outdoor activities and computers! In September I will be attending Cal Poly SLO, majoring in Aerospace Engineering.</p>
<p>This site, currently under construction using the Materialize framework, is proudly hosted on the Raspberry Pi 2, pictured below.</p>                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col s12 m6">
                        <div class="center-align">
                            <img style="padding-top:1%; padding-bottom:1%;" class="responsive-img materialboxed" src="pictures/pi2.jpg" alt="The new home of steelcowboy.me!"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="divider"></div>

                <h5>From running "fortune":</h5><p class="flow-text" style="font-size: 115%;">Real Users find the one combination of bizarre input values that shuts
down the system for days.
                </p>
                <div class="container center-align">
                    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/tags.png" class="responsive-img">
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script src="scripts/google.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please show us your CSS as well, and also create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) (or similar) to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: I dont have a solution for you at the moment, but the h3 has a margin that is forcing the white space down.

Comment: I use Materialize CSS, so besides everything in there the only other CSS is what's in my `<style>` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `overflow:auto` to container

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this selector:

```
h3 {
  margin: 1.46rem 0 1.168rem 0;
}
```

It is setting a top margin which is pushing down the rest of the container.

If you set `margin-top: 0` to that specific element, it should remedy the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The space is contributed by your heading, remove the top margin on it and you're good. The solutions below illustrates how to fix them using inline styles but you should really consider using css classes :)

Solution 1: remove top margin on the h3, either inline or via a css class.

```
<h3 class="center-align" style="margin-top: 0px;">Welcome to the site of James Heald</h3>
```

Solution 2: Add a top padding to the container, either inline or via a css class. This might be a better approach as it does not interfere with your h3 classes, since you might want the top margin elsewhere on your site.

```
<div class="container white" style="padding-top: 10px;">
```

To make the container span the whole height, make sure all parent elements has height: 100%. e.g.:

```
<main style="height: 100%">
  <div class="container white" style="padding-top: 10px; height: 100%">
    ...
```

Comment: That does exactly what I want for the top (so thank you for that!) but unfortunately it doesn't do the same for the bottom, so I feel like there should something that will force it to go from the top to the bottom -- like I said, flex *almost* works but messes up the content inside

Comment: for the bottom, add height: 100%; to both your container and main.

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick; however, I ideally would like everything to remain in place and only the white container expand as I want to keep this layout for all of the pages on my site and don't want to have to mess with the margins for the first element each time

Comment: Which browser are you on? Setting height to 100% on main and container worked for me. And I get you don't want to set margin top to 0, that's why I proposed solution 2 which is to add top padding on container.